# SQL Group By Column Without one value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(item.sel_item_id) AS 'Count'
FROM item
GROUP BY item.sel_item_table, item.sel_item_id, item.gold
```

with this result:

```
SEL_ITEM_TABLE SEL_ITEM_ID
pf_gem            2  ...
pf_gem            4  ...
pf_gem            3  ...
pf_weapons        4  ...
pf_weapons        2  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
```

I wish that the items in pf_weapons are always separated without the groupby, like this:

```
SEL_ITEM_TABLE SEL_ITEM_ID
pf_gem            2  ...
pf_gem            4  ...
pf_gem            3  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
pf_weapons        1  ...
```

Comment: So, is it returning `SEL_ITEM_ID` or is that column supposed to be the `COUNT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exclude the weapons, then union them back on.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(item.sel_item_id) AS 'Count'
FROM item
where item.sel_item_table != 'pf_weapons'
GROUP BY item.sel_item_table, item.sel_item_id, item.gold
union all
SELECT *, 1
FROM item
where item.sel_item_table = 'pf_weapons'
```

As noted by @Hogan in the comments, `UNION ALL` will be more performant.